# Why is my pdf uploaded using a presigned AWS S3 url does not have the correct content type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pdf, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

I use AWS S3 with presigned urls both for uploading (`putObject`) and downloading (`getObject`).

I noticed that the generated urls to load pdfs are downloaded instead of being displayed in the `_blank` target. I tracked it down to the fact that my s3 objects have a metadata field `ContentType` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/pdf` as I requested. It works when I manually change the content type metadata on S3.

The code used to generate the presigned `putObject` url is this:

```js
console.log("presigning with ", fileInput);
/* Will print something like:
presigning with  [Object: null prototype] {
  name: 'myFile.pdf',
  mimetype: 'application/pdf',
  size: 321528
}
*/
const { name, size, mimetype } = fileInput
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 60
let data = {}
const key = "articles/" + Date.now().toString() + ".pdf"
let params = {
       Bucket: 'mybucket',
       Key: key,
       Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
       ContentType: mimetype
};
data.url = await uploadToS3(params)// what I will use to upload from the client browser


export const uploadToS3 = (params) => {
    AWS.config.update({
        accessKeyId: process.env.S3ACCESSKEYID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.S3SECRETACCESSKEY,
        region: process.env.S3REGION
    });
    var s3 = new AWS.S3();
    return s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
}
```

The generated url contains indeed the content type option like follows (truncated url):

```
https://mybucket.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/articles/1582299553999.pdf?Content-Type=application%2Fpdf&X-Amz-Algorithm......
```

However, when I try to display my pdf in a `_blank` tab, the browser downloads it because of the faulty `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type set during the S3 upload.

I assume the `getObject` presigned url is ok since it works when I manually update on S3 the content type of the file.

Am I missing something with the upload?

---

**UPDATE**

I wondered if maybe it was related to the axios put request made on the basis of the presigned url. Based [on this issue comments](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/86), I managed to get the proper content type.

However, The pdf does not load because the favicon is not available... There is 2 network call, one for the pdf that ok with 304, and one for a favicon that gets a 400 bad request on firefox, and a 403 forbidden on chromium. As a consequence (it seems), the pdf file is seen as invalid.

I made the favico file the only public one, but the PDF is still seen as invalid. However, it displays correctly when downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For everyone's future reference, when sending a presigned URL request, you need to provide the Content-Type in the request, in the `axios`, or whatever is your http client. Otherwise it will be given this `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.
That's why when you retrieve with `.getObject` , you see the `Content-Type` set to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.